# Send email when specific product is bought (Prestashop)

Tags: php, email, prestashop

I need to send an email using Prestashop when specific product is bought.

Right now Presta sends two emails by default, one with confirmation and the other one with product list.

But in my shop I have four unusual products that need special instructions for client and I need to send them by email. All of those (four) products have the same category.

The only thing I found on the internet is that it might be tricky because of spam reasons - Presta does not allow it.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Show some code please :-)

Comment: But what can i show you? I don't even know what file i should edit or what module i need to install.

Comment: Then you need to hire someone

Comment: Wow, that's helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a module of your own (plenty of resources on the Internet for that).
It only needs to hook on `orderStatusUpdate` in my opinion.
Then have the function below in your module (you won't have a choice if you want the hook to work anyways):

```
public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params)
{
    $cart = $params['cart'];
    if($params['newOrderStatus']->id == 2) // payment accepted
    {
        $prods = $cart->getProducts(true);
        foreach($prods as $prod)
        {
            if($prod['id_category_default'] == 123456) //your category ID
            {
                $mailParams = [
                    '{my_email_var}' => "my custom value/link whatever you need"
                ];
                Mail::Send(1 /*language ID*/, 'name_of_your_template', Mail::l('Email subject here'), $mailParams, recipient@email.com, null, null, null, null, null, dirname(__FILE__).'/../../mails/');
                //that last param is needed if you put your mail templates (both .html and .text) in a mails/language_iso/ folder
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i haven't thought about creating module myself. Now i know where to start. Thanks once again!

Comment: You're very welcome, sometimes a small module is worth a try.